# How do I add a where clause to a sum aggregate?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out best way to get the aggregate of a person's hours spent on a project name that follows a certain pattern

### Current Tables

```
+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+
|    Tbl_Employee    |  Tbl Projects  |  tbl_timesheet  |
+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+
| employee_id        | project_id     | timesheet_id    |
| employee_full_name | cws_project_id | employee_id     |
|                    |                | project_id      |
|                    |                | timesheet_hours |
+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Here is the query I have so far

```
select
te.employee_id, 
te.employee_last_name,
te.employee_first_name,
te.employee_department,
te.employee_type_id,
te.timesheet_routing,
sum(tt.timesheet_hours) as total_hours,
month(tt.timesheet_date) as "month",
year(tt.timesheet_date) as "year"

from tbl_employee te
left join tbl_timesheet tt
on te.employee_id = tt.employee_id
join tbl_projects tp 
on tp.project_id = tt.project_id
where te.employee_active = 1
and te.employee_id > 0
and employee_department IN ("Project Management","Engineering","Deployment Srvs.")
and year(tt.timesheet_date) = 2015
group by te.employee_last_name, year(tt.timesheet_date), month(tt.timesheet_date)
order by employee_last_name
```

What I need to add to my select statement is something to the effect of

```
sum(tt.timesheet_hours) as where cws_project_id like '%Training%' as training
```

In short I need to know the sum of hours an employee has contributed to a project where the `cws_project_id` contains the word *Training*. I know you cant add a where clause to a Sum but I cant seem to find another way to do it.

If this makes a difference I need to do this several times - ie where the project_name contains a different word.

Thank you so much for any help that can be provided. I hope that is not clear as mud.

Comment: Why can't you just add `cws_project_id like '%Training%'` to your current WHERE clause?

Comment: Because I need multiple aggregates in separate columns. So I need a column where ``cws_project_id = %Training%`` and then a different column where ``cws_project_id = %Another Phrase%``

Comment: As a sidenote, if multiple people with the same last name work on a project in the same year, month, you are going to be merging their hours; it would be better to group on `employee_id` instead of last name.

Comment: thats a great point! Ill update the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general form of what you are looking for:

`SELECT SUM(IF(x LIKE '%y%', z, 0)) AS ySum`

even more general

`SELECT SUM(IF([condition on row], [value or calculation from row], 0)) AS [partialSum]`

---

Edit: For more RDBMS portability (earlier versions of MS SQL do not support this form of `IF`):

`SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [condition on row] THEN [value or calculation from row] ELSE 0 END) AS [partialSum]`

Comment: What if the condition is a reference to a column in another table as is the case with ``cws_project_id``?

Comment: I tried ``sum(IF(tp.cws_project_id like '%Training%', tt.timesheet_hours, 0)) as training_hours`` and it always returns 0 for me. I think I am a bit confused because of the grouping and the external reference to tbl_projects tp

Comment: @CullyMason your query has a lot of fields you didn't specify in your table "definitions", you should update your question to include the table `CREATE` statements. In my experience, fields with `id` suffixes tend to be integers, not strings; are you sure you do not need to join to another table to get something like a `cws_project_name`?

Comment: I would but the create statements for the tables have about 30 additional columns each that we dont actually need for this to work. the projects table has an id where it is an int, but the cws_project_id field is generated by our accounting system. I know not ideal, but it is what I am dealing with.

Comment: As long as the creates include all fields involved, they don't need to be complete; it would just help to determine what else might be interfering. Your attempt above looks like it should work if `cws_project_id` is a string field, so something else must be going on. Also, some example data from the fields could be useful. Are you sure anyone, **in the specified departments**, has had hours on "training" projects?